# Como buscar uma String dentro de um ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Estou com dificuldades na utilização da classe ArrayList, mais especificamente na busca de uma String. A questão é a seguinte, o meu código até funciona, mas quando cadastro mais de dois livros dentro do ArrayList, na hora de fazer a consulta ele só "encontra" o último livro cadastrado, não acha os anteriores.

**Essa é a minha classe livro:**

```
public final ArrayList<Livro> livros = new ArrayList<>();
// Atributos
private String titulo;
private String autor;
private String editora;
private String consultaLivros;
private int numPags;
private int pagAtual;

public void informacoes() {
    System.out.println("_____________________________________");
    System.out.println("Título: " + this.getTitulo());
    System.out.println("Autor: " + this.getAutor());
    System.out.println("Editora: " + this.getEditora());
    System.out.println("Número de páginas: " + this.getNumPags());
    System.out.println("Página atual: " + this.getPagAtual());
}

public void apresentacao() {
    System.out.println("_____________________________________");
    System.out.println("Título: " + this.getTitulo());
    System.out.println("Número de páginas: " + this.getNumPags());
}

// Getter e Setters
public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public String getAutor() {
    return autor;
}

public void setAutor(String autor) {
    this.autor = autor;
}

public String getEditora() {
    return editora;
}

public void setEditora(String editora) {
    this.editora = editora;
}

public String getConsultaLivros() {
    return consultaLivros;
}

public void setConsultaLivros(String consultaLivros) {
    this.consultaLivros = consultaLivros;
}

public int getNumPags() {
    return numPags;
}

public void setNumPags(int numPags) {
    this.numPags = numPags;
}

public int getPagAtual() {
    return pagAtual;
}

public void setPagAtual(int pagAtual) {
    this.pagAtual = pagAtual;
}

// Métodos
public void virarPagina(int pagAtual) {
    this.setPagAtual(this.getPagAtual() + 1);
}

public void consultaLivro() {
    System.out.print("Digite o nome do título a ser pesquisado: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    this.setConsultaLivros(input.nextLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < livros.size(); i++) {
        if (livros.get(i).getTitulo().contains(this.getConsultaLivros())) {
            livros.get(i).informacoes();
            System.out.println("");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Título não encontrado!");
            System.out.println("");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Esse é a classe principal:**

```
    entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    Livro book = new Livro();
    int verificarCadastro = 1;
    while (verificarCadastro == 1 || verificarCadastro == 2) {
        System.out.println("Bem vindo a sua biblioteca. ");
        System.out.println("Digite 1 para NOVO livro.");
        System.out.println("Digite 2 para CONSULTAR livro.");
        System.out.println("Digite 0 para SAIR.");
        verificarCadastro = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");
        switch (verificarCadastro) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Você saiu do programa.");
                System.out.println("");
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.print("Digite o nome do livro: ");
                entrada.nextLine();
                book.setTitulo(entrada.nextLine());

                System.out.print("Digite o nome do Autor: ");

                book.setAutor(entrada.nextLine());

                System.out.print("Digite o nome da editora: ");
                book.setEditora(entrada.nextLine());

                System.out.print("Digite o número de páginas: ");
                book.setNumPags(Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine()));

                System.out.print("Digite a página atual: ");
                book.setPagAtual(Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine()));
                System.out.println("");
                book.livros.add(book);
                break;
            case 2:
                book.consultaLivro();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Você digitou uma opção inválida.");
                System.out.println("");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tenho certeza que isto já foi respondido antes. Alguém acha uma duplicata?

Comment: `public void informacoes() {` não é um construtor.

Comment: Sua classe `Livro` tem um `ArrayList<Livro>` - Ou seja, você diz que um livro tem vários livros. Isso não parece ser uma modelagem orientada a objetos adequada.

Comment: Estou começando a programar orientado a objetos. Não sei o que seria uma modelagem orientada a objetos adequada, obrigado pela ajuda. Vou dar uma estudada mais aprofundada.

Comment: @VictorStafusa então, eu tinha feito um construtor mas acabei mudando de ideia, e no meio disso tudo acabei esquecendo de apagar o comentário. Obrigado pelo lembrete :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A resposta do Math](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/238633/132) já demonstrou o problema no seu método `consultaLivro()`. Mas há ainda outros problemas.

Basicamente, na sua classe `Livro`, você tem esses dois campos:

```
public final ArrayList<Livro> livros = new ArrayList<>();
private String consultaLivros;
```

Isso significa que cada livro tem vários livros e que cada livro tem uma `String` de consulta de livros. Isso não é uma modelagem orientada a objetos adequada, pois a lista de livro não pertence a nenhum livro. A `String` de busca também não pertence a um livro. Além disso, o campo `livros` é público, e você deve saber que não é boa prática manter campos de instância públicos.

Além disso, você não precisa do campo `consultaLivros` para nada, e nem o getter e setter correspondente. Veja no seu método `consultaLivro`:

```
this.setConsultaLivros(input.nextLine());

for (int i = 0; i < livros.size(); i++) {
    if (livros.get(i).getTitulo().contains(this.getConsultaLivros())) {
```

Observe que você lê um dado (`consultaLivros`), o coloca dentro do objeto e tira esse mesmo dado deste mesmo objeto. Isso daí é um dado que uma vez lido, só tem sentido dentro desse método, e uma vez finalizado o método, ele perde o sentido de existir. Além disso, só faria sentido armazenar isso na instância (`this`) se esse dado fosse transportado para algum outro lugar, o que não é o caso aqui pois o `consultaLivros` perde o propósito de existir dentro do mesmo método no qual ele nasce. Logo, isso deveria ser uma variável local, e não um campo do objeto. Assim sendo, já contando com as alterações do Math, o seu método ficaria assim:

```
public void consultaLivro() {
    System.out.print("Digite o nome do título a ser pesquisado: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String consultaLivros = input.nextLine();

    boolean achou = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < livros.size(); i++) {
        if (livros.get(i).getTitulo().contains(consultaLivros)) {
        System.out.println("O livro cadastrado está na posição: " + livros.indexOf(i));
        livros.get(i).informacoes();
        System.out.println("");
        achou = true;
    }
    if (!achou) {
        System.out.println("Título não encontrado!");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

E o campo `consultaLivros` e o getter e setter correspondentes podem ser apagados.

Como já mencionei antes, não faz sentido um livro ter vários livros ou um livro pertencer a outro livro. Aliás, é pior que isso. Na sua classe principal, você tem isso:

```
Livro book = new Livro();
// ... várias linhas de código aqui.
book.livros.add(book);
```

Esses são os únicos dois lugares onde você cria um livro ou o adiciona à lista de livros. Isso significa que:

- O seu sistema só tem um único livro (afinal de contas, você só instanciou ele uma única vez).
- Que a lista de livros vai conter várias vezes o mesmo livro.
- Que um livro contém a si mesmo várias vezes.
- Que um livro pertence a si mesmo múltiplas vezes.

Ou seja, isso daí não vai fazer nada que seja parecido com o que você quer.

Isso pode ser resolvido ao criar uma classe `Biblioteca` que contém uma lista de livros:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Biblioteca {
    private final List<Livro> livros;

    public Biblioteca() {
        this.livros = new ArrayList<>(10);
    }

    public void adicionarLivro(Livro livro) {
        this.livros.add(livro);
    }

    public void consultarLivro() {
        System.out.print("Digite o nome do título a ser pesquisado: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String consultaLivros = input.nextLine();

        boolean achou = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < livros.size(); i++) {
            if (livros.get(i).getTitulo().contains(consultaLivros)) {
            System.out.println("O livro cadastrado está na posição: " + livros.indexOf(i));
            livros.get(i).informacoes();
            System.out.println("");
            achou = true;
        }
        if (!achou) {
            System.out.println("Título não encontrado!");
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Além disso, vamos ver o seu método `virarPagina`:

```
    public void virarPagina(int pagAtual) {
        this.setPagAtual(this.getPagAtual() + 1);
    }
```

Observe que o parâmetro `pagAtual` não é utilizado.

Veja bem, no seu código, o `book.setAutor(entrada.nextLine());` está **alterando** o autor do livro, ao invés de estar **definindo** o autor do livro que está sendo cadastrado. Esse é um outro problema que tende a levar você a cometer enganos que fazem estar sempre alterando o mesmo livro ao invés de criar livros novos. Conceitualmente, quando um livro é cadastrado, ele já contém todas as informações necessárias para ser um livro e considerando que tenham sido cadastradas corretamente, não faz sentido que sejam alteradas. Ou seja, o construtor já deve devolver um objeto `Livro` pronto para uso, e não um esqueleto incompleto a ser consertado depois por meio da invocação de um monte de setters.

Outro detalhe, é que os métodos `setPagAtual` e `virarPagina` não respeitam o número de páginas do livro. Você não pode virar a página se já estiver na última.

Abreviar nomes (ex: `pagAtual`) também não é boa prática de programação. Use `paginaAtual`.

Considerando tudo isso, eis a sua nova classe `Livro`:

```
public class Livro {

    private String titulo;
    private String autor;
    private String editora;
    private int numeroPaginas;
    private int paginaAtual;

    public Livro(String titulo, String autor, String editora, int numeroPaginas, int paginaAtual) {
        if (numeroPaginas <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        if (paginaAtual <= 0 || paginaAtual > numeroPaginas) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.editora = editora;
        this.numeroPaginas = numeroPaginas;
        this.paginaAtual = paginaAtual;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(String autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public String getEditora() {
        return editora;
    }

    public void setEditora(String editora) {
        this.editora = editora;
    }

    public int getNumeroPaginas() {
        return numeroPaginas;
    }

    public void setNumeroPaginas(int numeroPaginas) {
        this.numeroPaginas = numeroPaginas;
    }

    public int getPaginaAtual() {
        return paginaAtual;
    }

    private boolean paginaExiste(int numeroPagina) {
        return numeroPagina >= 1 && numeroPagina <= numeroPaginas;
    }

    public void setPaginaAtual(int novaPaginaAtual) {
        if (!paginaExiste(novaPaginaAtual)) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.paginaAtual = novaPaginaAtual;
    }

    public void virarPagina() {
        if (paginaExiste(paginaAtual + 1)) this.paginaAtual++;
    }

    public void voltarPagina() {
        if (paginaExiste(paginaAtual - 1)) this.paginaAtual--;
    }
}
```

Não é boa prática de programação misturar lógica de visualização (seja ela `System.out.println`, telas e layout desktop, HTML, android, etc) com lógica de negócio (que é aquela que define o que o seu sistema faz e como se comporta). A ideia é que uma mesma lógica de negócio deveria ser capaz de ser expressa e manuseada independente daquilo que é utilizado para exibi-la e interagir com o usuário, o que a torna portável para vários ambientes. Entretanto, sempre que você usa um `System.out`, um `JOptionPane` ou um pedaço de HTML dentro da sua lógica de negócio, você joga essa premissa por terra. Há ainda outros vários motivos para não se misturar essas coisas (mais sobre isso abaixo).

Assim sendo, retirei os métodos `informacoes()` e `apresentacao()` da sua classe `Livro` acima. Vamos refazer a sua classe `Biblioteca` pensando nisso:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Biblioteca {
    private final List<Livro> livros;

    public Biblioteca() {
        this.livros = new ArrayList<>(10);
    }

    public void adicionarLivro(Livro livro) {
        this.livros.add(livro);
    }

    public Optional<Livro> consultarLivro(String consultaLivros) {
        for (Livro book : livros) {
            if (book.getTitulo().contains(consultaLivros)) return Optional.of(book);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

O `Optional` é um objeto que pode ou não conter um outro dentro. Se conter, significa que aquilo que era produrado foi encontrado. Se não, é porque não foi encontrado. E note que o método `consultaLivro` se preocupa apenas em consultar o livro e devolvê-lo se for encontrado. Não é responsabilidade dele pedir ao usuário qual é o livro a ser consultado e nem exibir esses dados em qualquer lugar. Uma vez que esse método está desacoplado da lógica de visualização, você não vai se ferrar se quiser colocar as informações do livro em um arquivo ao invés de colocar no `System.out`. Algo parecido pode ser argumentado acerca do `System.in`.

Por fim, as suas classes principais:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Optional;

public class CadastroBiblioteca {
    private final Scanner entrada;
    private final Biblioteca biblioteca;

    public CadastroBiblioteca() {
        this.biblioteca = new Biblioteca();
        this.entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void lerLivro() {
        System.out.print("Digite o nome do livro: ");
        String titulo = entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Digite o nome do autor: ");
        String autor = entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Digite o nome da editora: ");
        String editora = entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Digite o número de páginas: ");
        int numeroPaginas = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Digite a página atual: ");
        int paginaAtual = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());

        biblioteca.adicionarLivro(new Livro(titulo, autor, editora, numeroPaginas, paginaAtual));
    }

    public void consultarLivro() {
        System.out.print("Digite o nome do título a ser pesquisado: ");
        String consulta = entrada.nextLine();

        Optional<Livro> opt = biblioteca.consultarLivro();

        if (!opt.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println("Título não encontrado!");
            return;
        }

        Livro livro = opt.orElseThrow(AssertionError::new);
        System.out.println("_____________________________________");
        System.out.println("Título: " + livro.getTitulo());
        System.out.println("Autor: " + livro.getAutor());
        System.out.println("Editora: " + livro.getEditora());
        System.out.println("Número de páginas: " + livro.getNumeroPaginas());
        System.out.println("Página atual: " + livro.getPaginaAtual());
    }
}
```

```
public class SistemaBiblioteca {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CadastroBiblioteca cadastro = new CadastroBiblioteca();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Bem vindo a sua biblioteca. ");
            System.out.println("Digite 1 para NOVO livro.");
            System.out.println("Digite 2 para CONSULTAR livro.");
            System.out.println("Digite 0 para SAIR.");
            String verificarCadastro = entrada.nextLine();
            System.out.println("");
            switch (verificarCadastro) {
                case "0":
                    System.out.println("Você saiu do programa.");
                    return;
                case "1":
                    cadastro.lerLivro();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    cadastro.consultarLivro();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Você digitou uma opção inválida.");
                    System.out.println("");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Dividi em duas para separar o menu da implementação das funcionalidades.

Comment: Nossa Victor, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Estou aprendendo a programar OO agora e essas suas considerações sobre o meu código ajudaram bastante. Obrigado mesmo! Estou implementando os códigos aqui e tentando entender eles, e alguns conceitos até agora desconhecidos!

Comment: ótima análise !

Answer (score 4):

Na sua consulta você varre a lista mas interrompe o loop logo no primeiro elemento sendo o titulo do livro encontrado ou não ao utilizar os `breaks` dentro do `if` e do `else`

```
for (int i = 0; i < livros.size(); i++) {
    if (livros.get(i).getTitulo().contains(this.getConsultaLivros())) {
        System.out.println("O livro cadastrado está na posição: " + livros.indexOf(i));
        livros.get(i).informacoes();
        System.out.println("");
        break; //AQUI
    } else {
        System.out.println("Título não encontrado!");
        System.out.println("");
        break; //E AQUI
    }
}
```

Você pode tirar os breaks e deixar a lista ser varrida completamente, e a mensage de "Título não encontrado" ser emitida fora do loop, assim:

```
boolean achou = false;
for (int i = 0; i < livros.size(); i++) {
    if (livros.get(i).getTitulo().contains(this.getConsultaLivros())) {
        System.out.println("O livro cadastrado está na posição: " + i);
        livros.get(i).informacoes();
        System.out.println("");
        achou = true;
    }
}
if (!achou) {
    System.out.println("Título não encontrado!");
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Veja funcionando em no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/10s5Nb)

Comment: Pessoal, eu testei o código com as mudanças e o erro persiste. Ainda continua só achando o último livro cadastrado.

Comment: @Math estava fazendo um teste para ver a quantidade de livros cadastrados, se estava atualizando. Esqueci de tirar :) hehe