# Meu código só pega o último elemento do banco de dados

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Meu código só pega o último elemento do banco de dados, porém ele lista a quantidade correta de lá e o `log.i` mostra que está pegando todos. Por que isso não funciona?

```
package br.app.lista;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CatalogoTodos extends Activity {

    private Livro livro;
    private Catalogo_Livro_Lista catalogoListaTodos;
    private ListView listTodosCatalogoId;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private  SimpleCursorAdapter ad;
    //private String[] aaa = {"teste","teste1","teste","teste1","teste","teste1","teste","teste1","teste","teste1","teste","teste1"};




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.catalogo_todos);

        listTodosCatalogoId =  (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listTodosCatalogoId);
        db = DBHelper.getDatabase(this,"livro");
        livro = new Livro();

        String listar = "SELECT * FROM livro";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(listar,null);
        ArrayList<Livro> lv = new ArrayList<Livro>();

        if(cursor.getCount() >0){

            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                livro.setIsbn(cursor.getString(0));
                livro.setTitulo(cursor.getString(1));
                livro.setSubTitulo(cursor.getString(2));
                livro.setEdicao(cursor.getInt(3));
                livro.setAutor(cursor.getString(4));
                livro.setPaginas(cursor.getInt(5));
                livro.setAnoPublicacao(cursor.getInt(6));
                livro.setEditora(cursor.getString(7));
                livro.setCategoria(cursor.getString(8));
                lv.add(livro);

                Log.i("RESULTADO -" , "TITULO: " + cursor.getString(0));
                Log.i("RESULTADO -" , "AUTOR: " + cursor.getString(4));

            }
            catalogoListaTodos = new Catalogo_Livro_Lista(CatalogoTodos.this,lv);
           // ArrayAdapter<Livro> livroadapter = new ArrayAdapter<Livro>(CatalogoTodos.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lv);
            listTodosCatalogoId.setAdapter(catalogoListaTodos);


        }else{
            Toast.makeText(CatalogoTodos.this, "Nenhum registro encontrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

    public void voltarCatalogoTodos (View botao){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Catalogo.class));
        finish();
    }


}
```

```
package br.app.lista;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


public class Catalogo_Livro_Lista extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Livro> livros;
    private Activity activity;

    public Catalogo_Livro_Lista(Activity activity, List<Livro> livros) {
        this.livros = livros;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return livros.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return  livros.get(position);

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Livro livro =  livros.get(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View linha = inflater.inflate(R.layout.catalogo_livros_list,null);
        TextView nomeLivro = (TextView) linha.findViewById(R.id.txtNomeLivroId);
        TextView autor = (TextView) linha.findViewById(R.id.txtAutorLivroId);
        ImageView fotoLivro = (ImageView) linha.findViewById(R.id.imgLivrosId);

        nomeLivro.setText(livro.getTitulo());
        autor.setText(String.valueOf(livro.getAnoPublicacao()));

        if(livro.getImagemLivro()!= null){

            Bitmap imglivro = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(livro.getImagemLivro());
            fotoLivro.setImageBitmap(imglivro);


        }else{

            Drawable draw = activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lupa);
            fotoLivro.setImageDrawable(draw);

        }


        return linha;

    }
}
```

Comment: Dê uma lida em [ask]

Comment: Quase duplicata disso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/238627/132

Answer (score 3):

Quantas vezes você instancia a sua classe `Livro`?

Resposta: Uma. Logo, você tem apenas um livro!

O lugar onde você instancia é aqui:

```
        livro = new Livro();
```

Esse é o **único** lugar onde você dá um `new Livro()`. Como isso não está dentro do laço, então apenas um livro foi criado.

Dentro do `while` você faz isso:

```
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                livro.setIsbn(cursor.getString(0));
                livro.setTitulo(cursor.getString(1));
                livro.setSubTitulo(cursor.getString(2));
                livro.setEdicao(cursor.getInt(3));
                livro.setAutor(cursor.getString(4));
                livro.setPaginas(cursor.getInt(5));
                livro.setAnoPublicacao(cursor.getInt(6));
                livro.setEditora(cursor.getString(7));
                livro.setCategoria(cursor.getString(8));
                lv.add(livro);

                Log.i("RESULTADO -" , "TITULO: " + cursor.getString(0));
                Log.i("RESULTADO -" , "AUTOR: " + cursor.getString(4));

            }
```

Ou seja, você está **alterando** o livro definido ao invés de estar **criando** um novo livro. O que você deveria fazer é algo assim:

```
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Livro livro = new Livro(); // <--- Observe essa linha.
                livro.setIsbn(cursor.getString(0));
                livro.setTitulo(cursor.getString(1));
                livro.setSubTitulo(cursor.getString(2));
                livro.setEdicao(cursor.getInt(3));
                livro.setAutor(cursor.getString(4));
                livro.setPaginas(cursor.getInt(5));
                livro.setAnoPublicacao(cursor.getInt(6));
                livro.setEditora(cursor.getString(7));
                livro.setCategoria(cursor.getString(8));
                lv.add(livro);

                Log.i("RESULTADO -" , "TITULO: " + cursor.getString(0));
                Log.i("RESULTADO -" , "AUTOR: " + cursor.getString(4));
            }
```

**Remova** essas duas linhas que estão fora do `for`:

```
    private Livro livro;
```

```
        livro = new Livro();
```

Isso deve resolver o seu problema.

Também faço a sugestão de que troque isso:

```
        ArrayList<Livro> lv = new ArrayList<Livro>();
```

Por isso:

```
        List<Livro> lv = new ArrayList<>();
```

Há outros problemas e possíveis melhorias no seu código, mas para não ficar muito repetitivo, veja [essa outra resposta minha numa outra pergunta parecida com a sua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/238720/132), em especial a parte que falo sobre evitar construtores vazios e sobre misturar lógica de visualização (`Toast.makeText(...)`) com lógica de consulta ao banco de dados.

Comment: ola Boa Tarde Victor..vlw pelas dicas e pelo comentário. então fiz todas essas alterações, fiz um código menor e mais simples pra ver melhor aonde eu estou errando,
Porem o erro persiste, eu estou usando a IDE Android Studio e acho que deva ser um bug, pq fiz no eclipse Android na facul e rodou...
Muito grato